# What's with all the username suffix symbols?

Tags: discussion

I know that the users with a Ψ suffix are SE employees, and of course ♦ means it's a moderator.

But I'm seeing a handful of other greek characters too, like Φ - is that just other users being funny, or are there more "task force" teams à la [CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character)?

Here are some random examples:

- [Alain Pannetier Φ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5432/alain-pannetier)
- [aedia λ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8732/aedia)
- [drɱ65 δ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/dr65)

Comment: Links? However, I suspect it's other users being funny.

Comment: For example [KevΩ ♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev) carries both the unofficial and official regalia.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164012/) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/) as well?

As those two are not part of any task force as far as I can tell, it means they renamed just for fun probably after the Ψ task force announcement. Can't tell for all cases though, but I'm pretty sure that we'll have blog post in case of any additional task forces.

Note that many change their names only here in Meta while leaving "normal" name in the main sites.

Comment: Omit the "obviously" and I'm all with you. It isn't all that obvious to me, hence this question.

Comment: I meant just those two.. can't tell if it's global. Will edit anyway to make it more clear. :)

Answer (score 6):

Your first guess is correct: **this is just users being (attempting to be?) funny**.

I assume it all started with [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100223/should-psi-be-a-reserved-character-for-usernames-to-prevent-impersonation), specifically Kevin's response, which says that there is no feature specifically in place to limit people adding certain symbols like psi (Ψ ) to their user name. He basically *dares* us to do so, I mean come on, what goes through *your mind* when you read this:

> If you want to pretend to be one of the cool kids, whatever; it doesn't affect anything.

I actually thought about doing it myself, but then I realized it was kind of lame. Score 1 for laziness.

Sadly, of course, you still can't add a diamond to your user name. Michael Mrozek's insightful comment to the linked question spares the rest of us from having to try that for ourselves.