# Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter, question-restrictions

Recently this Mathematica question was posted, [Mathematica can't DSolve two-body pro-ble​m?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613946/mathematica-cant-dsolve-two-body-pro-blem) The reason for the odd split in the word *pro-blem* is there is a filter preventing its use in titles. For the most part, I can see where this is useful, as almost by definition all questions asked here are about problems. But, this filter prevents a legitimate use of the word that is accepted in the physics and math communities.

Is there a way around this, or is the problem so great that its legitimate use must be suppressed also?

Comment: There are also several valid uses of "problem" related to algorithms on SO, e.g. the subset-sum problem, or NP-complete problem. I think this filter should either be removed or demoted to a warning.

Comment: Now that we have [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104914/add-title-uniqueness-to-the-heuristics-for-detecting-low-quality-questions/106796#106796) we probably could just get rid of that restriction.

Comment: @Arjan, apparently there isn't a filter on meta.

Comment: A [Unicode Ux200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b) zero width space might help, but that's a workaround obviously, and not a very nice one.

Comment: I wish they'd stop coming up with these dubious point-solutions for verbiage problems.  There are always unintended consequences, and they can *always* be worked around.

Comment: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html), by Jeff himself

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I feel you kind of missed the point with that edit ;-)

Comment: @NullUserException, I see you [applied a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7613946/revisions). Just in case you didn't realize it: beware that this breaks searching for the word (at least in the title; not a big issue I guess) and of course: the invisible character will be confusing for others.

Comment: @Arjan It's not a big deal since it's included in the body: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bmathematica%5d%20problem

Comment: I know, @NullUserException, just wanted to make sure you know what effect it might have. (And few people, if anyone, will use `title:"two-body problem"`.)

Comment: A partial solution might be to ask for verification before posting something with "problem" in the title (but most users will probably just click "yes"), or allow users with a certain number of reputation points to use the word "problem".  (Not that I advocate either solution; I'd rather just remove the restriction altogether.  Inappropriate uses of the word can always be edited out.)

Comment: One time on an entertainment device I had to enter my name, so I put "Crunchy Grass". :D I couldn't do it because of the last bit of grass.

Comment: The same thing apparently works with "question" and "help". I would *like* it if the system suggests that I not use those words. But I do **NOT** like it when I can't use those words when I really mean to do so.

Comment: @JasonS the difficulty with some of these words is that they're likely to be low quality questions, which I can understand. Yet, there are legitimate uses for some of these words, like "how to set a help menu?"

Comment: Then let the **community** edit the title, not a lame bureaucratic **system**. Doing so reduces the quality of this site the way those damned voice mail systems do ("Press 1 if you want to check your balance. Press 2 if you want to find the date of the last payment. Don't bother pressing 0 because we've fired all the human operators.")

Comment: @JasonS I didn't say I disagreed, only that's the reasoning.

Comment: Why not make bypassing/overriding the word filter a reputation privilege?  Then if it's a legit use, the community can edit the Titles to correct/allow them?

Comment: I'm waking this up with a bounty.  Can we get some action here?

Comment: @ErickRobertson got my vote.

Comment: Bountying as I'm having a problem with this.

Answer (score 139):

As Jeff himself [once pointed out](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html), word filters are an extraordinarily bad idea.

This prevents people who have a [legitimate reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles) (as well as the site's [most trusted and privileged users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115007/moderators-should-be-immune-to-the-word-filters-in-titles)) from using the word "problem" in the title, and people who just don't care will simply work around the filter by deliberately misspelling the word or simply inserting a space or punctuation:

- [Image upload **proble** in drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879502/image-upload-proble-in-drupal) ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:proble))
- [Where can I find an optimal solution to the Knapsack **proble***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896922/where-can-i-find-an-optimal-solution-to-the-knapsack-proble)?
- [sendmail issue “mail loops back to me MX **pr0blem**” centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130867/sendmail-issue-mail-loops-back-to-me-mx-pr0blem-centos)

and the *pièce de résistance*:

- [GeForce GT555M Cuda **Problam**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8197711/1)

This is 100% useless and does more harm than good.

---

**Expanded:** [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-the-worst-idea-ever-implemented-on-so)

Comment: Presumably a proBLAM is a problEm which causes an explosion.

Comment: Oh, ow, apparently [plurals are able to squeeze through this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198540).

Comment: Googling "The N+1 Problem" brings up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem as the first result. Wouldn't be possible under today's wordfilter.

Comment: **None of your examples make up for good question titles.** "Image upload proble in drupal" *What image upload problem?* "optimal solution to the Knapsack proble?" *Define optimal? What problem? What have you tried? Why did it fail?* "loops back to the MX pr0blem" *No need for pr0blem in that title, it's fine without that word.* And the Coup De Grace "Cuda Problam" *What problem is he experiencing?*

Comment: @TomWijsman Whether or not they are good titles to begin with is not the issue here. The filter makes them *worse* titles, that's all I am saying.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: The real question is how much percent are worse titles, if that's just small then the filter is really worth it.

Comment: @meagar - I see that question has since been edited and the title now refers to the "n+1 selects issue" !

Comment: @TomWijsman The word "problem" in most of those examples refer to known mathematical problems - the "problem" is part of a proper noun, and should not need to be mangled.

Comment: @Marcin: You appear to be addressing different examples.

Answer (score 35):

I believe that the team is simply trying to raise the level of discourse on Stack Overflow, and I fully support this decision and applaud their efforts.

In order to contribute to the general sense of erudition, and following the [adoption of Greek letters as insignia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101695/whats-with-all-the-username-suffix-symbols) here on Meta, I therefore propose a grass-roots campaign to substitute the Greek "πρόβλημα" (transliteration: *problema*) for any and all occurrences of the English "problem", as well as any manglings thereof ("porblem", "pr0blem", etc.).

A [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) should be formed with two tasks: to educate the user base, via comments and in chat,* about this new practice; to perform the necessary edits; and to recruit other members to the posse...

*Three* tasks: to educate the user base, via comments and in chat,* about this new practice; to perform the necessary edits; to recruit other members to the posse; and to evaluate the expansion of this policy to the web as a whole...

**Four tasks**: education of the user base, editing, recruitment, evaluation of expansion to the rest of the web, and proposal to the team of technological means of reinforcement...

The posse's tasks *should include* education, editing, recruitment, expansion, and proposal of technological aids, amongst *any others* which may be deemed appropriate, now or in future.

As an intermediate solution, the team should auto-convert all instances of the English "problem", network-wide, whether in titles or otherwise, to the Unicode string "�������", i.e., seven `U+FFFD` "[Replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)"s.

---

*As well as off-site means of communication (e.g., Twitter) as appropriate.

Comment: Or, as I found out just recently, you can use "problems". Works quite well.

Answer (score 22):

I've come up against this same issue, with: [How to tractably solve the assignment optimisation task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982127)

The "Problem" in this case is the "Assignment Problem", another well known algorithmic problem.

Clbuttic.

Comment: "Optimizing the assignment trollface.jpg"? ;)

Comment: And another one - the [Monty Hall Prob lem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247863/102441)

Answer (score 9):

May I suggest stackoverflow to tweak the filtering mechanism such that questions containing phrases such as:

- "**a problem**" - as in "I am having a problem with this question"
- "**this problem**" - as in "Can someone explain how to solve this
  problem?"
- "**the problem**" - as in "Can somebody fix the problem?"

OR beginning with:

- "**Problem**" - as in "Problem dealing with this issue"

are filtered (case-insensitive) instead? Going by the number of up-votes on this question, it is quite clear that the word "problem" should not be a problem ;)

Comment: Not another filter! Just remove it altogether!

Comment: What about the title "**_Error when trying to foo the bar: "a problem has occured"_** " or something similar?

Answer (score 8):

I think the devs can turn it off for Mathematica.

[It's off for Physics anyways](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=problem)-- half the questions are *legitimately* titled "problem". The other half usually get renamed. Usually.

Edit: I misread the question, I thought the post was *on* mathematica.SE (where it should rightly be). In that case, I vote to demote the "problem" filter to a warning.

Comment: Ah, but the original problem was for a question here on SO. Can they make it tag specific? Also, SO has more intense filters because of the volume of questions.

Comment: @rcollyer: Oh that question is supposed to be migrated to mathematica.SE anyways, right? (I guess I misread the question--I sort of assumed it was on mathematica.SE)

Comment: I'm not sure we want it. It's not a great question, and it is still loosely on-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

As someone said, it's better to educate the user base. How about adding a helpful tooltip which asks : Re-consider if you can state your question without using the word "problem" (and follow up the request with a link as to why the word "problem" might not be such a good idea in a title in some cases)