# Cannot edit question without also changing the title

Tags: feature-request, edits, title, quality-filter

I tried editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973934/problem-saving-row-with-doctrine). It has "problem" in its title, so when I try to save it, I get a warning box telling me I should avoid using this word in a title. And I can't save my edit unless I change the title, which will make the edit non-atomic. I think only the OP should get this warning. Getting a box asking me to please change the title after my edit would be fine too.

Comment: So remove "problem" from the title

Comment: @squillman : very funny

Comment: What do you mean by "non-atomic"?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: it's not necessarily the word I was searching for, but I mean that my edit will not contain two unrelated changes. This way, you can rollback it and leave other edits that might be fine easily. The meaning is the quite the same as in "an atomic commit"

Comment: @random: Yes, I guess "feature-request" is more appropriate than "bug"

Answer (score 7):

My 2¢: Not changing a title should basically not trigger the banned words check. There are multiple reasons to edit questions without changing the title. Manual cleanup of tags comes to mind (for the OCD crowd, of which I am a member).

Comment: +1 I just got bumped *three* times while editing an old question to move in the content of a follow-up that was posted as an answer. First I had to change "problem" to "issue" and then the title had to be changed twice more because other questions had the same title...

Comment: ...although, admittedly, that could mean that me being forced to change the title was justified in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

The word "problem," among a few others like "question" have been blacklisted and you can't use them in question titles anymore. The question was probably created before this filter was in place (that's why the OP managed to post it), but now you can't edit anymore. You'll have to either remove it or work around it.

For what it's worth, I think this (the word filtering) is a terrible idea.

See related question: [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)

Comment: Terrible idea indeed... what if I only want to change the formatting, but don't understand the question well enought to change its title?

Comment: Just use a word that is synonym of _problem_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno No, please don't just use a synonym that we'd eventually have to blacklist as well.  Make the title more descriptive instead.

Comment: I edited my question to highlight the issue

Comment: @BilltheLizard What if the word "problem" has a legitimate use? (see my related question link)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ Damn corner cases!  How does your work-around work?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I added a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) to "problem"

Comment: @BilltheLizard If it were me to edit the title, I would not use a synonym of _problem_. As greg0ire seems to say he is not able to give a better title to the question, the only suggestions left (apart from what suggested in this answer) are to use a synonym of _problem_, or avoid editing the question.

Comment: If you live in a house without corners, there aren't corner cases. `;-)`

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ Ah, that's why I couldn't see it in the revision history.  That does break search though, so I wonder if it would be better if the filter just didn't block words that were delimited somehow.  Maybe if "two-body proble​m" was quoted?  Still not perfect, of course.

Comment: @kiamlaluno This isn't one of those corner cases though, since there are much better titles for that question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That won't work either. And I think the OP has a legitimate concern: what if they just want to improve formatting but can't think of a better title?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ I disagree that it's a legitimate concern in this case. I only had to read the question to come up with a better title to that question, something you'd naturally do while improving the formatting.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I didn't mean it was one of those. It is just that the OP is asking for support, he receives the right answer, and says he doesn't know which title is better. I start thinking that the support is "edit the title for me, so I can edit the question myself."

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I'm not a native english speaker, so It'll be much easier for me to improve the formatting than to improve the title. Besides, I'm a nice guy : I'm fixing the formatting. So why *annoy* **me** (and not the OP) into fixing the title?

Comment: @kiamlaluno : my question is not "please come up with a title for me", but "please remove this functionnality" (if you can call this a functionnality). I didn't tag this question "support" but "bug", someone changed the tags.

Comment: @greg0ire The original question was not clear about that; only after you added a new sentence that explains the purpose of the question.

Comment: Indeed. I rollback the tags to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Just give it a more descriptive title.  See [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6973934/revisions) for an example.  (If there are any other edits you wanted to make, you should be able to now.)

The same warning does now appear when posting new questions.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Do you mean "now" or "not"? I misread.

Comment: @greg0ire: it's now. If someone tries to ask a question with the word 'problem' or 'question' in the title, the question is not accepted. So the problem you had with that edit won't happen on new questions.

Comment: @Mat: Ok, too bad this occured on question that were posted before this development was deployed...

Comment: I guess it solves the "problem", because this warning will only affect the OP now.

Comment: @greg0ire Not it won't. You should think about unaccepting the answer and wait until this is marked 'status-planned', 'status-declined', 'status-deferred' or 'status-completed' by an admin.