# Make edition of tags not trigger title validation

Tags: feature-request, edits, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot edit question without also changing the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108069/cannot-edit-question-without-also-changing-the-title)

I decided to cleanup some tags yesterday, but a lot of older questions had troublesome words in the title. You know the kind: error, problem, issue.

So while we all know these words are bad (hmmkay?), making a would-be editor fix the title, just because a question had, in the past, a word that is now banned, that's just a pain.

Granted one should not be allowed to change the title to add the banned words, but if, on submit of edit, the title is the same, please just allow it to pass the filter.