# The 'do not use these words in titles' issue: should you prohibit or warn?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the word “problem” in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)

I once tried asking the question:

> Understanding the Drools planner examples: where is the problem state initialized?

The question cannot be submitted because:

> please do not use these words in titles: 'Problem'. See Writing Good Titles

The word was part of the phrase 'problem state' (no, such a phrase doesnt exactly exist!), not indicative of a poorly phrased question.

---

Is it right to prevent a question being posted based on some 'bad words' in the title? Or should it merely have a warning similar to "the title appears subjective..."?

---

I got around the restriction by misspelling 'problem' in [Understanding the Drools planner examples: where is the problm state initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923851/understanding-the-drools-planner-examples-where-is-the-problm-state-initialized)