# Work Around for Legitimate uses of Blacklist Words in Title

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the word “problem” in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)

Is there a work-around for the (apparently new?) title word ban?  The following

["There was a problem‍​​ with reindexing process." after product import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304574/magento-there-was-a-pr0blem-with-reindexing-process-after-product-import)

while not a shining example of a good question, does attempt to do one thing right by putting the exact text of the error message in the question title.  However, as that error message included the word "problem", the poster had to shift to a less than graceful workaround.

I attempted to edit the text to remove the "`133t`" workaround, and was blocked from editing the question due to it's use of the word "problem".  Again, this is a verbatim repting of the error-message/exception text from the user's system.

If there isn't a work-around, please consider this a feature-request.  Exact error messages in titles is good for people answering the question, as well as for people googling for the topic.