# Can we have an answer filter when it more than X % of it is links?

Tags: feature-request, answers, filtering, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

On Super User, I usually come around posts containing something like:

> [Some software product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) allows you to do Y.

Now imagine that that answer would instead be:

> [Some software product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) allows you to do Y.
>
> In order to do Y:
>
> 1. Do this instruction.
> 2. Do that instruction.
> 3. Do another instruction and you'll get what you want.
>
> Note that it also allows you to Z, but not A, B and C.

Or would include a portion introduces software product, which allows the user to choose without clicking.

> [Some software product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) allows you to do Y.
>
> > Application software, also known as an application or an "app", is computer software designed to help the user to perform specific tasks. Examples include enterprise software, accounting software, office suites, graphics software and media players. Many application programs deal principally with documents. Apps may be bundled with the computer and its system software, or may be published separately. Some users are satisfied with the bundled apps and need never install one.
> >
> > Application software is contrasted with system software and middleware, which manage and integrate a computer's capabilities, but typically do not directly apply them in the performance of tasks that benefit the user. The system software serves the application, which in turn serves the user.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > [image]

**Exactly! Can we just filter out the first form which procentually has not enough non-link text?**

Comment: In some cases though, it literally *is* a case of just a link being sufficient. Its a technical solution to a social problem that can be handled by edits, comments and downvotes, and would be worked around with ridiculous padding or blind copypasting.

Comment: If the answer is just a link, I usually edit the answer to include a summary of the software, derived from it's website/about page. It doesn't solve the problem, but it helps others get an idea, so they aren't clicking blindly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a considerable amount of filtering in place, with the review system heaping shame upon the short answers that do make it through. Simply *blocking* lackluster answers doesn't automatically result in the creation of outstanding ones...

There has to be a balance here between blind algorithms and intelligent reviewers / editors. I'd prefer that we erred on the side of creating slightly more work for the latter, unless there's a *huge* payoff. Indeed, a barely-adequate answer can provide motivation for posting an excellent one.

It's too easy to solve one problem [while creating another... uh... Pro-blem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles).

Comment: If you think it would introduce another problem, then I'm fine this is  not being implemented. But just wanted to have a little less work on our part such that the poster would do a little bit more than just pasting a link...

Comment: On a second thought, **how would a warning function?** It totally makes sense not to block it, but we could at least mention they could add a little more...