# How do I ask a question about asking the user a question?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to post [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130006) originally with a title like "How can I ask the user a quesion before saving?" and StackOverflow told me that I wasn't allowed to use the word "question" in my title. Is this some sort of mechanism to prevent meta questions on the main site? Is there a way around it for cases where I'm actually asking a legitimate question that uses the word "question"? In my case, I ended up writing a new title using the word "query", but my original wording was more concise and to the point.

Comment: There's a technical term you can use, like "open a message box" instead of "ask a question."  It's more specific and meaningful anyway.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles

Comment: As an aside: I am impressed by just how meta you have got here: asking a question about asking a question about asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a quality filter to reduce poor-quality questions. You can't use the word "question" (and some others) in your question title. Of course it stops some legitimate uses of these words in question titles, but overall those who evaluate the efficacy of the filter seem to be of the opinion it does more good than harm.