# Could we ban the words 'Titan' and 'Bengal' in the same post for a while?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, spam

I have been participating in the mass-flagging of the spam that is coming through SE, trying to recruit viewers for live football streaming stuff.

The community is handling it well, and a single post is usually alive for no more than 10 minutes, but it would be better if we didn't even have to deal with it.

Therefore, I would propose that a question not be allowed into the system if it contains the words 'titan(s)' and 'bengal(s)' in either it's title or body.

I can't see any way this would break the system. Any ideas?

Comment: My worry would just be that the spammers would quickly realize what was up and get around it.

Comment: But it's all about the Giants vs Oilers next week

Comment: Yes - it's my worry too. However, it would seem to put quite a crimp on their style, judging from their posts.

Comment: @random Hmmm... So should I not name my new HTML Regex parsing library "Giants vs Oilers"?

Comment: Maybe SE should automatically take the big games and ban them in titles?

Comment: Many sports and matches to take your fancy https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=watch+live+streaming+site:stackexchange.com

Comment: @random Oh gosh. **Kill with fire!**

Comment: This question would be blocked then in the future and all posts about that on meta.

Comment: @juergend 'temporary'. And maybe not on Meta.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is it not possible to IP ban the spammer for the meanwhile? Are they using a proxy?

Comment: @Undo It's very likely that they are using something like Tor and switching exit nodes on very post so it looks like every spam post is from a different IP making an IP ban useless.

Comment: What about Dolphins and Texans? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294314/how-to-free-watch-miami-dolphins-vs-houston-texans-live-broadcast-streaming-pres (10K only) Picking particular teams won't work. Even picking other words like "streaming", "broadcast", "free", etc can be gotten around in cheesy ways ("fr3e stream!ng!")

Comment: More successful would be something like [Bayesian spam filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) based on words in previously flagged posts, but it would certainly be a massive project to implement it on a site this size.

Comment: @Undo - Let's just say that IP bans would be ineffective here. We'd need to cut off pretty much the entire nation of Bangladesh to deal with these people, and there are 50-100 users on some of the IPs they've connected from.

Comment: Yeah, because [title word filters are such a great idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This type of approach to spam is just playing the cat and mouse game, it's impossible to keep up with the bots this way. And of course the more filters you add the more you will have [false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=titan+bengal).

I don't have a solution to offer other than continued community moderation (which we agree is working well), but I really disagree with the approach you suggest. Spam will come in many forms, these types of quick-patches don't work and over time they can become unmanageable.

Answer (score 5):

> [Watch all the Titian and Been gals games here and win big!](http://example.com)
>
> [Place your bets on Oil E.R.s v Gnats now!](http://example.com)

Need I continue?

Comment: Why are the Oil Emergency Rooms fighting Gnat, anyway?

Comment: Click the link and find out, @AndrewBarber!

Comment: Ahhh! My eyes! ;)

Comment: Yes, there _is_ an awful lot of grey there.

Comment: Yeah. I think I'm rooting for the Oil ERs, now! poor Gnat...

Comment: hey! don't confuse my real spam filter with your hypothetical spam.

Comment: There's nothing hypothetical about it, @jandvorak. Example.com gets spammed all over the place, in the guise of using it as an examp... oh, err... nevermind..