# Should we ban the term "vanilla javascript" from questions, comments and answers?

Tags: discussion

In regards to the term "vanilla javascript" (or "vanilla js" for the hipsters), people fall into tree categories:

1. People who know what the term means
2. People who don't know what the term means
3. People who think they know what it means, but are wrong

For those of you in groups 2 and 3, the term "vanilla javascript" simply means "plain javascript", i.e. javascript that doesn't rely on any third party libraries (such as JQuery).

Now, the problem I find with the term is that for those that don't already understand the meaning, it is not obviously clear what is being implied. Of course, any able reader of the term should be able to take some initiative and find out what it means themselves. The problem here though is when [the top Google result turns out to be this](http://vanilla-js.com/) - not exactly helpful, and unless you really read into it, an unwitting reader may actually think "vanilla js" is a real 3rd party javascript library.

My overall point is that this term only provides confusion for users here on SO. When new-to-programming users come along and ask simple questions such as "what is the different between this code (plain JS) and this code (JQuery)?", an answer of "the first is vanilla JS" is completely useless and misleading!

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18491718/838807), though in this instance the term is used in the first comment (I have seen it used in answers before though)

So what do you think? Should it be banned?

Comment: What would banning the term achieve?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: It would ensure that we are not promoting confusion in our answers. Shortcuts to sentences, just for the sake of saving some typing, are (IMO) bad when they add confusion. The ban can be either be enforced via text replacement, or just made a social rule that those of us that care enough can agree to follow for the good of mankind

Comment: I don't think we can ban a term just because a lot people don't know what it means.  The site is full of technical jargon.

Comment: 1) Enforcement doesn't work for stuff like this 2) The only people who would follow such a social rule are the people who already do anyway (i.e. already avoid using the term "vanilla JS").

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I agree with the technical jargon, but it is generally used in the correct context and is likely yo be understood by the person asking the question anyway. I am yet to see an example of "vanilla js" that has been used to make things easier to understand, or directly answer a question

Comment: "Vanilla" to mean "standard" is actually a *general term*, not specific to technical or sex (BDSM) discussion, though those are the two situations where I see it most often.

Comment: @TRiG: I appreciate that, but when it comes to modern technology, there are so many trendy names for things that it's hard to tell when someone means plain javascript, and which someone mean and actual version of javascript called Vanilla

Comment: Can't even go with [standard js](https://github.com/christopherliu/standard-js) either...

Comment: Yeah. Actually, a *lot* of software products are given confusing names, apparently deliberately. I am aware of some forum software called Vanilla.

Comment: Yes, because word bans [have worked so well before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles).

Comment: brb, creating 'plain.js' framework.

Comment: I have never fallen into, or from, a tree category.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like vanilla either. Let's call it *chocolate javascript* instead.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see what this would accomplish. While Vanilla JS is a bit of a meme all on its own, it's pretty self explanatory. If we disallow the use of that term, then we have:

- Plain
- NoQuery
- Just javascript
- Zero framework

.. all of which are fine for indicating that you can't, or wont, for whatever reason, use a JS framework in your project, so stand alone solutions would be preferred. A bigger problem is getting folks to stop using terms like `jquery variable` and `json object`, because those *are* technically misleading and perpetuate their own misnomers simply by existing, but that's another discussion.

And, well, nothing is stopping someone from 1 - Googling the term or 2 - posting a comment like:

> What is Vanilla JS? I don't understand what you mean.

As it's becoming more or less a standard way of expressing not using a framework, I don't see why we'd want to impede it.

Comment: ban jquery, its spam in search results

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with a couple of your premises here;

First, I think that 'vanilla javascript' is a fairly efficient term to use to describe what it means. No matter what term you use, some will need to have it explained. I suspect an analysis of the number of words used in explanation of it would balance out. But mostly, I don't think there's any evidence it's a big enough problem to worry about at all.

Second, I disagree that even if it *did* need to be explained a lot, that banning its use would be at all helpful. People would simply choose a different term, but *banning* just doesn't feel like the right tool regardless.

Comment: People should choose a different term... "plain javascript"

Comment: @musefan Banning "vanilla javascript" is not the best way to get people to use a different term. Even assuming there is a compelling reason to make them use that other term. We generally do not try to enforce such things, unless they become a real disruption.