# Struggling to understand Stack Overflow's philosophy

Tags: discussion, etiquette, post-ban, answer-quality

I'm new here and find the prevailing attitude and tone of the site extremely authoritarian and offensive.
It is certainly **not** encouraging one to participate and share opinions etc.

I have just been banned for "low quality answers" which is hardly a good way to encourage participation by people new to a particular field.

If it were not for the fact that this site comes up so often in Google searches for information, I'd just shake the dust off my sandals and leave you all to your own devices.

So - end result - you have ensured that I will never again attempt to contribute to this site.   You are all so clever obviously you don't need my help or opinions.  A pity, as my philosophy is usually to try to give (where I can) and not just take help from websites.

I have been looking for help in a couple of areas that I'm very new to (which is what led to my recent discovery of SO).   Has it occurred to you that just because I may be new in one or two areas I may actually know something about other areas?

This is one strange place.

PS:  Just to rub salt into the wound, you wait until I have spent 20 minutes composing my comment and hit enter to tell me I'm banned.   Nice one!

Comment: Is this a question that can be answered or is it just a rant?

Comment: Stack Overflow tries to be the place to go to for **quality** questions and answers. That means we have standards that have to be met, yes, because otherwise you'll never find the many gems we have collected among the muck. That is **why** the site keeps being found in Google searches.

Comment: We do try to give you as much help and guidance as possible before you post; when you [asked here on Meta about a recommendation question you posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207494/saying-anyone-can-ask-a-question-is-deceptive-when-you-close-their-questions) you got a lot of feedback as well as to why we do things the way we do them. That is not elitist, that is being **clear** and focused. Stack Overflow was **never** the place for *every question you can think of*.

Comment: I'm really sorry you're having a bad start here, but looking through your questions it's not clear that you've read anything about this site _before_ posting. You, like many others, seem (I might be wrong) to have assumed that you can post whatever you want. Have you considered that rather than the site being authoritarian and offensive that you have been lazy and rude by not reading anything about the community you have joined? It is not that difficult to get on well with the SO community and hundreds of thousands of people have managed it....

Comment: ... If you read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) you should be able to get a clear idea of what the community's about. Anyone can be a great member, it takes no special talents, and I'm sure you have the ability. It'd be great if you could. I particularly believe that having multiple differing methods and people is the way to get the best out of everyone concerned... it stretches everyone to think, as long as everyone respects everyone else.

Comment: Yes I suppose it is a question wrapped in a rant.   I did try to be polite.  My apologies if Ive offended anyone.

Comment: So far you've posted three times in the "Your Answer" box, all three of which were new questions.  In doing so, you ignored a dialog that pops up telling you to make sure you're *answering the question*.  So yes, you're banned from posting again until you read the instructions on how to use the site.  That's how Stack Overflow got to be so high in the Google rankings, by having *some* quality standards.

Comment: Ah, if you're banned from answering questions with a question that's not such a bad thing. You could ask questions instead :-). I would strongly recommend reading the help pages first through...

Comment: perhaps i will when ive calmed down a bit.   this site really is out to get me today it seems.   i just got an edit rejected on my last post cos i spent more than 5 minutes thinking about what i actually wanted to say.

Yes I saw the pop up, which to be ones I didnt really undertand.  I took it to mean that comment was on topic.  

If you are supposed to start a new thread instead, is there a way to link it back to the original one?   Maybe Im not clear about comment vs answers... I guess Ill have to look for that in the hekp pages.

Comment: @RFlack You can always just include a link back to annother question in a question, however such a link should be extra information. The question should be able to "stand alone"

Comment: @RFlack For context; stack overflow was created to solve the problem of forums; that the answer was buried in amoungs assorted other posts, requests for clarification, wrong answers, other questions in no real order. That is why we are so strict that an "answer" must answer the question

Comment: @RFlack this is Q&A = no thing like "threads" here. Just questions, answers, and for people with some reputation, comments. Ideally all comments can be purged once question is clarified, fixed et cetera. Even better if they are not needed at all.

Comment: Im not sure I care now, but ..
am I correct this is a lifetime ban?  It reads that way.
To participate you need "points".   Looks like I cant get any sice i cant post or comment outside of here.
I suppose I can always create another account.  If I really cared.

Comment: @RFlack It depends, it doesn't "timeout" but nor is it lifetime. If you get upvotes on your answers then the algorithm will recalculate and the ban may end. You can achieve this by editing your remaining answers to be better. Asking good questions may also help

Comment: @RFlack no, not a lifetime ban! if you will fix your answers, it will be lifted. So just be careful not to delete them / fix them before they are deleted. Yes, deleted bad content still counts for the ban. Even more than not deleted one.

Comment: All your answers appear to be deleted however, which limits our options. If you think you can improve them flag any of your own questions asking them to undelete the answers you think you can improve explaining that you are trying to lift the ban

Comment: Sorry Im utterly confused.
I dont understand what you mean by fixing my answers.   Since Im banned I cant post.  Plus Im not sure I wouldnt just dig the hole deeper anyway.

Comment: RFlack You can't *post* but you could *edit* - if there was something worth being an answer... See what @RichardTingle just wrote.

Comment: @RFlack You could still edit your answers. However, we then discovered that all of them are deleted which would require a mod to undelete

Comment: @RFlack Creating an account won't help - the ban is at a lower level than account (IP ban, I think). It appears that you have been using answers to ask questions - consistently, after repeatedly being told not to. I suggest you post the things you posted as answers as new questions (make sure they are **high quality** questions though! you don't want to be q-banned too!).

Comment: What is the point of purging comments when question is clarified?  Wouldnt some of them contain useful background / conext / alternative point of view, whatever?

Comment: @RFlack Anything that answers the question should be in an answer. Anything else is transitory and can be deleted (it often isn't, but it can be)

Comment: @RFlack Then that should be edited into the question. Comments are like temporary little post it notes.

Comment: I guess I need new glasses!  You say "after repeatedly being told not to" ... well, I have to say however that message was being expressed, I totally did not understand what was being said.  And I am pretty good normally at dealing with this sort of thing.

Comment: @RFlack First time you didn't understand, you should have asked here on Meta :(

Comment: You were forced to read a "how to answer" page and check a checkbox **specifically saying** that you understanded.

Comment: Oh yeah, and [this huge popup box thingy](http://i.imgur.com/p9bCEex.png)... not sure how you can miss that (I created a dummy account to see what answering is like for new users

Comment: `If it were not for the fact that this site comes up so often in google searches for information` This is like saying "That city is too strict and authoritarian about littering. If it weren't for the fact that its streets were so clean I would never go back."

Comment: What I didnt realise was the difference between a comment and an answer which I guess is my fault, (to me they are all 'responses', but lets not get into that) but the huge pop up box doenst really tell you how to comment.
From here on in Ill just ask questions.
And keep my information /opinions to myself.
Thank you all for all the advice.

Comment: David ... my underlying question is really about how discouraging the site is to new users (eg no warning that I had erred before being suspended) and how does one get past the learning curce.

Comment: "the huge pop up box doenst really tell you how to comment" of course it does not, because you should avoid it, if feasible. It tells you how to answer when you post an answer, why should it cover totally unrelated action?

Comment: Related proposal; [After an answer is deleted as “Not An Answer” give a timed message box before posting the next answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211450/after-an-answer-is-deleted-as-not-an-answer-give-a-timed-message-box-before-po)

Comment: And you came here with misunderstandings on what this site is all about. This is not a site that encourages people "to participate and share opinions etc." as you put it. Answers should consist of solutions to the stated problems only, not opinions or discussions or new questions. If that philosophy chases away new users, then, well, sorry but it may not be the right site for those new users.

Comment: Seems like things are working as designed here.

Comment: For the record, I absolutely do **not* agree with the On-Hold reason.  This question is specifically seeking input from the community.  Aside from that, my suggestion would be to peruse some questions and answers with lots of upvotes.  See what they did, and use that knowledge going forward.  Yes, SO can be a bit trying for new users, and there are plenty of questions here on Meta that address it.  I get your frustration, believe me!  But I have never once in my 65 years of life seen someone say, "You're an ass" to another person, and that person turns around and sees the error of his ways.

Comment: Johnny:  I think it may have been do to the original question which was superficially more of a statement (as I said earlier, had a question (or three!) wrapped in a rant.  Well a mild rant, I thought I kept it polite.   
I think I understand a little more.   I HAVE read quite a few threads though not with the specific goal of seeing what gets the most votes; more to get a flavour of the sort of comments and expertise being posted here.   And I must say its quite confusing, to me anyway.

Comment: Another "clue" I suspect is the acceptability here of editing other peoples posts.  Thats the first time Ive seen  it.  My initial reaction was how dare you!  Im also struck by someone taking the time to correct the typos and lacunae in my post here... yes Im lazy about apostrophes etc, Im too used to self-correcting editors.  But thank you nonetheless.  I will probably post some questions about what is permissible in editing someone else's posts. How far can one change the sense of what was posted etc.  Let me read more first tho.   
Anyway - fascinating education for me.

Comment: I thought it was one of the most polite rants ive seen in quite some time.

Comment: Stack overflow is a community edited site. Any edits that do not change the meaning of the post are permitted

Comment: Welcome to wiki-style, RFlack ;) In other sites I'm like: "ups, there's a typo here; oh, the title can improve; ***where** is the `edit` button?*" ... And yes, please look for guidance on how editing works, so you can have a spot-on start.

Comment: Now we can go SERIOUSLY off-topic with Wiki dragged across the trail.  But I won't rise to the bait other than to mention that Wiki articles are anonymous.  So "community editing" may make sense.  Posts here are not.   Yes I need to find out more about editing, but I do find it unsettling that something with my name on May not actually be my product.

Comment: @rflack: I think you're spot on with your characterisation, it was my first impression when I first looked over the site and I was very reluctant to get involved, you're doing well to keep away, a lot less waste of your time. You should see it as a badge of honour that this post has been down-voted so badly, and good luck with what ever you are doing now.

Comment: You will find that people edit posts for all sorts of reasons other than the ostensible reason of correcting grammar, spelling etc; mainly, as a way of showing approval or disapproval, to signal advice, this happens a lot when certain people are working together in a loose fashion, watching out for each other - yeah, I know, it sounds like a coterie. Anyway, it's worth looking out for ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding the downvotes to your this *meta* question, you should understand that voting on meta is [a bit different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) than on the actual site.

Now, getting to the main question, if you really would like to contribute & be a part of [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) (one of many sites in the [Stack Exchange network](http://www.stackexchange.com/sites)) you should [take a tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first! We at Stack Overflow are a very good **professional** community, hence, to keep up our standards and quality of the content on our site, have to follow some set guidelines and norms.

You are one of the many people who come to get involved, but for some reason, don't follow the beginner guidelines. As a result, you do face difficulties. I recommend you at least [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which will guide to the working of the site. If you have time at your hands, you should also go through all of the [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) if you are looking forward to be a part of the community.

I can understand your frustration, but that is how the community works! Without a set of rules & active moderation, Stack Overflow would not have been what it is today.

We do like opinions, but they must be professional opinions. For more on that, check out [What is On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You got banned for low-quality answers, so you *must* take a look at [Why you were banned & what it means](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) & also [How to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And, like I said, we are a community of professionals from various fields, we have [Our own model for expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) so that no one is offended in the process of participation.

If you are an expert in some areas, your answers (neatly written and useful in the future as a reference) would definitely help others and I highly recommend you to answer them. Since you are new to certain fields, you can always ask your difficulties faced, with proper code and background of the problem being faced (all relevant info) & many in here would gladly help you out.

Finally, I recommend a fresh start at this, [mending up your mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). Good luck! Hoping to see you in the community!

Comment: Well, it seems about the only thing left I can do is ask questions.
I cant comment I cant post as that needs reputation.  Seems to be a catch 22.   I guess eventually if I ask enough approved questions Ill have enough points to contibute.  (An interesting concept: qualifictaion to answer questions is needing to ask a lot of questions LOL).   Anyway ... Im off to more useful actuvity.
Thanks again eveyrone especially Ashish for a symathetic response.
Yes I did look at the help stuff, but obvioiusly not enough.

Comment: You can actually edit your deleted answers, make them look good & then  undelete. This might also help in removing your answer ban. If you need really need help on your answer, you can `flag` your own answers for moderator attention.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Do you remember the link to recently deleted answers? Maybe it would help OP to go and do it. Sadly, I can't remember how it looks like (hardly ever needed to use it, and when I needed it it wasn't yet implemented).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Molot. @RFlack - Please use this link to your deleted answers http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/241718. You can find the link at the bottom of the `answers` tab in your StackOverflow profile.

Comment: @ Ashish  Your link gives page not found!!   Just not my day here it seems LOL.

Comment: @RFlack `An interesting concept: qualifictaion to answer questions is needing to ask a lot of questions LOL` - not quite. [You only need 1 rep to post questions or answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), and it is impossible to have less than 1 rep. The only exception is when you have been banned from doing so, which only happens when you show a repeated pattern of disregarding the rules and treating this site like umpteen other forums and lower-quality communities out there.

Comment: @RFlack You should check this link then - http://stackoverflow.com/users/2979783/rflack?tab=answers
I found my deleted answers link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It just  says 0 answers.
I think realistically I just have to be patient, keep asking questions as they arise (and Mutagen / Python issues not to mention Python on iOS which is a separate project, looks like that wont take too long lol), and then see if I venture out again or not.

Comment: Well, you could drop by in the chat if you want & ask some moderator to give you the links to your deleted answers. Good luck.

Comment: @rf Also, be aware that there are rules for questions as well. See [ask]. Better still, check out some well-written questions for an example of how to write a good question. Can't find any examples right now, tho.

Comment: yes i have seen the rules about questions.   Dont ask for help, right?  :)  etc.   Somehow those came across my radar more clearly than the comment / answer issues.

Comment: 10 years on, and nothing has changed. XD  Quote: "...you should understand that voting on meta is a bit different..." And herein lies the ultimate irony, as well as the exact problem stated in the main post.  From the link: "...voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change...."  --- So we have the community explicitly stating (through the votes on this very page) that we do _not_ wish to change to be more open, less authoritarian, nor more humble.  Not a surprise at all to me, but apparently this irony has been completely lost to the in-group.

Answer (score 16):

You appear to have been using **answers** to ask other questions. **DON'T DO THAT!**

Also,

> ... well, I have to say however that message was being expressed, I totally did not understand what was being said.

Umm... not sure how you don't understand this huge animated sliding popup thing:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>(I just created a dummy account and tried to answer a question)</sup>

You also should have probably noticed when your "answers" kept getting deleted.... If you didn't understand, you could have posted here on meta *before* being banned too.

Anyway, in order to get out of the answer ban, there are some options:

- Improve your existing answers! (not sure if this is possible from what I've seen) You'll have to get them undeleted first.
- Or, the more likely option - you were asking questions in the answer section. Well, **ask them as... an actual question!** Make sure they are high-quality questions (you don't want to be q-banned too!) If you contribute in the form of questions, the answer ban can be lifted.

Ah, one more thing: you keep referring to "comments" and "threads." The only "comments" are the ones right under the questions and answers, and there's no such thing as a "thread." **Stack Overflow is *not* a forum.**

Comment: Ban him! Sock puppet account!

Comment: @Duncan Ahhhhh! *throws hands up in air* :P

Comment: @Duncan - Im not sure what you are suggesting but it doesnt sound nice.  From what Google tells me it seems you think I am somehow deceptive or that this is not a real account. Im sorry you think that way.   At least some other people here have tried to give me helpful advice.
I leave it to others to judge if your comment is appropriate.

Comment: @RFlack He was refering to Doorknob creating a second account to test new user functions, and he was joking

Comment: Ahhh sorry, my bad.   Duncan pls ignore my comment.  My sense of humour is working too well right now :)

Answer (score 5):

Information technologists are stereotypically not the most personable folk you'll ever meet. Don't take feedback too personally, but on the other hand, do bear it in mind as it will help you gauge the culture of the site.

However, you'll always do well on SO by (i) asking sensible well-posed questions, (ii) providing good answers and (iii) editing questions and answers to improve them. You'll advance your knowledge in your field: I have.

Comment: What do you mean! we're lovely! ;)

Comment: We are friendly. We just don't bother with social rules of friendliness ;p

Comment: It's not necessarily that we're unfriendly, or unpersonable.  When people asking questions don't even do the most simple of research, or do not *want* to learn (just give me the code!) it is unsurprising that a low of new users get a harsh response from the community.  **WHY AM I GETTING OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT PLS HLP** <-- like that.