# Show a warning when posting a programming question here on Meta

Tags: feature-request, questions, meta, filtering

There are some questions posted here on Meta that are clearly programming questions.

In my opinion, I believe that Stack Exchange should check the title. Anything with "python" or "java", for example will be warned with a popup or some other notice.

By doing so, there will be less need to waste our precious time to flag the question.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this would be for meta, I was very confused for a second

Comment: @RichardTingle I hope this is featured on meta, so its tagged: Feature -request

Comment: Of course the trouble is most programming questions don't have the programming language in the title and many questions about problems in a certain community ("Loads of spam on the java tag") do

Comment: Yes, but feature requests are for the entire network unless you specify otherwise. Meta is for all feature requests

Comment: Can you guys explain why there is a downvote etc.?

Comment: Warned with a popup? And you're sure those kinds of people who post programming questions on Meta will read that popup?

Comment: @slhck i said 'etc.'

Comment: @leonneo Votes on meta are different, it (can) mean that people disagree, although your question is a little unclear as well

Comment: What is "etc."? You cannot outright ban posts with a title including the name of a programming language. And users already get lots of information about what (and what not) to post here. It's not like we need *more* popups and banners and messages.

Comment: @leonneo Why do you assume we are the absolute arbiters. Make your case, try to convince people. I may not agree, but others might

Comment: Now with the edit, it says 'some other notice'.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am trying really hard to adapt to meta, because i need to convince people.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177485/how-can-we-reduce-off-topic-questions-on-meta

Comment: @leonneo you're welcome, the grammar and the way you explain are both critical here on Meta. If you will add a mockup of what you have in mind it would also help.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is a feature request.

Comment: @leonneo I know, I mean add example of the message/notice you have in mind and where exactly it will show.

Comment: @leonneo That you made in paint etc. For example see my mockup in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211450/after-an-answer-is-deleted-as-not-an-answer-give-a-timed-message-box-before-po)

Answer (score 11):

While I understand the premise behind this idea I fear it has a number of problems

- Many programming questions don't have a language in the title

> "Please help!"
>   "Code won't work!"
>   "When I run the foo bar happens"
>   - who am I kidding, we never get good titled meta programming questions
>   etc

- Many non programming questions do have a language in the title

> "Code formatting is broken on the java tag"
>   "There’s a problem in the C++ community with ...."
>   etc

For example here are [2000 posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=java) with java in them that are not deleted

- People who post programming questions on meta don't seem to read anything ever, so a pop up is unlikely to faze them.

### Conclusion

For those reasons I believe this would have more false positives than real postives which would make it more of a distraction than a help: every wrong popup makes people less likely to read the next popup

Comment: At least it will cut down on the number of incorrect posts.

Comment: @leonneo Making submit fail 3 times out of 5 would cut down number of incorrect posts, too. The point is not to cut down the number of *valid* ones in the process.

Comment: There should be buttons like: 'Continue posting' and 'go back'.

Comment: @leonneo Trust me, if you have users read more and more text, at some point they will just stop reading and post whatever they want. I recently signed up for a forum where I had to read dozens of messages and guidelines before I could post something, and my brain just shut down eventually—so I clicked *Post question* without thinking. And I'm the type of person who usually tries to read FAQs and whatnot.

Comment: Introduce penalty when the question is closed.

Comment: @leonneo Now thats an entirely seperate feature request

Comment: @leonneo what penalty? most of the users have no rep.  And users who continually do it getting have there meta account suspended.  By why would you punish someone for making a minor mistake on time.

Comment: @leonneo I think the main problem is that there are [so many](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=java) on topic questions where this is true (2000 with [java] alone) that this won't work. It would need a better algorithm

Comment: Leave warnings.

Comment: @leonneo Like this one you mean; http://imgur.com/1gkDUSZ

Comment: @leonneo i think we do tht always .. any time this type of question put on hold moderator will give some warning on comments

Comment: @leonneo what kind of warnings?  What purpose would those warnings serve.  More often than not one of the close voters usually leaves a comment.  If you are talking about a real mod message (not a comment on the post), that leaves a permenant mark on the users account.  Why would you punish someone for making a mistake.

Comment: Don't forget that we deal with such question fast, swiftly and with *fanatic* precision. So if the volume of these doesn't start to pickup *massively*, it's nothing but a "oh, another, closed" side-thought. ... I somehow miss the Calvin-Comics, though.

Comment: I understand now.