# Should moderators have a special symbol on their display picture?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, moderators, symbols

Just wondering should there be a special icon or something on a moderator's display picture so we get to know he is a moderator on Stack Overflow?

Comment: There's a diamond next to my name.  See it?

Comment: Yeah I see it Robert. Well it is only a suggestion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not if the person [is on drugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-moderator-election-qa-question-collection#comment714617_220394). :)

Comment: If you're on drugs, the mods all look like squares.

Comment: Squares ... you mean squirrels?

Comment: How often do you see a moderator's display picture unaccompanied by their display name and diamond though? I only know of chat userlists and widgets. In the vast majority of cases, it's actually the other way around - display name and diamond unaccompanied by display picture.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-already-ready-already] That's two today!

Comment: No, I don't see a diamond next to your name, @RobertHarvey. :P

Answer (score 11):

I like the diamond, simple and clear.. Or do you want something like this:

[image]

Comment: All tests on Robert Harvey ;)

Comment: [You spelled modrator wrong](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png).

Comment: @Yannis You spelled *modrater* wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> Each moderator has a **Diamond** symbol(♦) next to his display name.

Like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel that the current symbol, a diamond, is too modest.

---

Mods should have glorious symbols, something ancient-Greekish or something.

My humble 2¢

Comment: What's more glorious than a symbol that represents thousands of people losing their hands and lives in order to fund the De Beers mystique

Comment: Maybe a gold crown or something on their picture.

Comment: Greek is too pedestrian. [Every Tom, Dick, and Harry had a Greek letter two years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101695/whats-with-all-the-username-suffix-symbols?lq=1).

Comment: I gotta admit that `Anna Lear 2¢` does have a certain ring to it...

Comment: ancient-Greekish? I'm in! And to further support this, I'll start writing all my Meta answers in Koine from here on.

Comment: Are you actually fluent in Koine, @Yannis? Anyway, why Koine and not Classical?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Koine, being the first common ancient Greek dialect, is a lot closer to modern Greek, and thus much easier to learn (if you already know modern Greek, that is). That said, I'm nowhere near fluent. I can read it (well, sort of), but haven't written anything in it since high school. And that was a million years ago.

Comment: @Yannis. My granddad was from Cyprus, and knew several forms of Greek, including Koine.