# Tag List Sometimes Truncated in iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ios-app

The tags on this screenshot read "feature-request stackoverflow moderators symbo"

On many other posts, the tag list wraps. I don't know what makes this one break. Possibly because it almost didn't need to wrap, so didn't trigger the new line.

[image]

Link to sample question: [Should moderators have a special symbol on their display picture?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220442/should-moderators-have-a-special-symbol-on-their-display-picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're manually adjusting positions to decrease horizontal space but in this case were increasing it. Fixed in the next build.