# Animated images crash the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

In a recent question about [moderators getting a special symbol on their display picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220442/should-moderators-have-a-special-symbol-on-their-display-picture), there was an animation playing. If it stays in view until it's complete, the app crashes. If I scroll down, out of view, the app lives. I tried restarting the phone, no change.

- Phone: [LG Optimus G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Optimus_G)
- Stack Exchange Android app version: 1.0.8
- Android version: 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220442/should-moderators-have-a-special-symbol-on-their-display-picture

Comment: Not reproducible on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, StackExchange 1.0.8, though it made the performance look sluggish (but not crashing).

Comment: Not reproducible on SGS II, 4.4.2 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been fixed by signing in on a Wi-Fi network. Exact cause is still unknown though